# C# implicit operator MyType(int value) automatically "supports" cast from float

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion, integer, implicit-conversion

When I implement cast operator from int to my type, it seems to "automagically" supports casting from float as well. I don't want my type to be implicit-casted from float! I don't want it to be even explicit-casted from float (defining explicit cast from float is not good enough).

Can I prevent such behavior?
Is there some specification explaining this?

**Reason:**
I'm trying to learn/explore deterministic fixed-point math and casts from float are generally "danger-zone". Int casts are fine and needs to be implicit. In cases where float casts are needed, I prefer static method to better specify the intent, eg: `MyNumber.ParseUnsafe(0.1f)`.

```
public struct MyNumber
{
    public int raw;

    public static implicit operator MyNumber(int x)
    {
        return new MyNumber { raw = x * 10 };
    }
}

public static class Test
{
    public static void TestSomething()
    {
        MyNumber num = (MyNumber)0.1f; // This must be compiler error, but it isn't!
    }
}
```

Comment: *This must be compiler error* - will be if you use a float that won't fit in an int

Answer (score 2):

[The language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#standard-conversions) says:

> A user-defined explicit conversion consists of an optional standard explicit conversion, followed by execution of a user-defined implicit or explicit conversion operator, followed by another optional standard explicit conversion.

So there *is* an explicit conversion from `float` to `MyNumber`. It is a "user-defined explicit conversion", consisting of a conversion from `float` to `int` (which is a "standard explicit conversion") followed by the execution of your implicit conversion operator.

[This section explains this in more detail.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#processing-of-user-defined-explicit-conversions)

An idea to try to stop this would be to try to find a type `T` such that there is a [standard explicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#standard-explicit-conversions) from `int` to `T`, but not from `float` to `T`, that also doesn't lose information. I can't think of such a type off the top of my head, and I think it's unlikely that this exists :(